# Regarding complexity of an algorithm with steps C(n+r-1, r-1)

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

If an algorithm requires
C(n+r-1, r-1) steps 
to solve a problem, where n is the number of input,
and r is a constant,
does the steps of algorithm consider exponential growth？

Comment: C is combination say C(3,2) means 3 choose 2 = 3

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I can't see the answer from that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that *C* is the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) function: `C(n + r - 1, r - 1) = (n + r - 1)! / ((r - 1)! * n!)`. Since *r* is a constant, we can disregard `(r - 1)!` when using the big-O notation, so we get `O((n + r - 1)! / n!)`. I assume that this might be homework, so try to take it further from here by yourself. It is possible to reduce `(n + r - 1)! / n!` to a quite simple expression since it is inside of an `O()`, and you'll then easily see whether or not it is exponential. (Hint: how many factors are there in `(n + r - 1)! / n!`?)

Comment: Thanks, this is not a homework, and I am rephrasing some other of my working problem into this algorithmic problem. But from your tips, (n + r - 1)! / n!=(n+r-1)*...*(n+1)..which is O(n^(r-1)) meaning this is polynomial rather than exponential, am I right?

Comment: @william007: Correct - it is even _Theta(n^(r - 1))_. Note, though, that if the restriction that _r_ be constant is dropped, this would no longer be the case.

Comment: @william007: Glad to help. Out of curiosity, what was the original problem?

Answer (score 0):

No. the complexity would be **`O(n^(r-1))`** which is a **polynomial growth** instead of (and better than) exponential growth.

```
let g(n) = C(n+r-1, r-1) 
         = (n+r-1)! / ((r-1)!n!)  
         = (n+1)(n+2)...(n+r-2)(n+r-1) / (r-1)!
         = n^(r-1) + kn^(r-2) + k'n^(r-3)... k''n + k''' / (r-1)!

it's easy to say that k,k'...k'',k'''and (r-1)! are all constant,
so T(g(n)) = O(n^(r-1))
```